# Intuition behind Huygens-Fresnel formula

Tags: optics, waves, visible-light, quantum-optics

I'm currently studying Optics, and I stumbled upon another alternative way in which to derive the Intensity Distribution of light through a slit.

My question is, why does the formula work. $U(r_{0}) \propto \frac{U_{0}e^{ikr_0}}{r_0} $ where $U_{0}$ is the complex amplitude at the point source, and $r_{0}$ the distance from the point source. (See picture below for more clarification).

I suppose more specifically too, why is there an inverse relationship between the distance and the amplitude at that point. Is this just due to Huygen's principle and its ever expanding wavelets? I always thought it's an inverse square relationship when it comes to light but I suppose this is wave optics after all...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{U_\mathrm{o}e^{ikr_\mathrm{o}}}{r_\mathrm{o}}$ is the correct form for the *electric field* $E$ of a point source. The inverse-square relationship arises when you calculate the intensity of the field, which is proportional to the norm squared of the electric field: $I\propto|E|^2=\frac{|U_\mathrm{o}|^2}{r_\mathrm{o}^2}$.